# Longest contiguous sequence BACKWARDS

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a method that searches forwards through an array and finds the longest contiguous sequence. Now I'm trying to create a method which searches BACKWARDS through an array and find the longest contiguous sequence.

So for example if the array input is {5, 56, 5, 4, 3} longestForward should return 5, 56; and longestBackward should return 3, 4, 5, 56.

The forwards method works perfectly but I am having trouble trying to make the backwards method work.

```
//Input array
int[] a= new int[]{5, 56, 5, 4, 9};
//Call method longestForward
longestForward(a, a.length);
longestBackward(a, a.length);}


 public static void longestForward(int a[], int size){
   int maxstart = 0;
   int max = 1;
   int start = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
     if (a[i] > a[i - 1]){
       if (i - start + 1 > max){
         max = i - start + 1;
         maxstart = start;}} 
     else{
       start = i;}}
   System.out.println(max);
   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
     System.out.print(a[maxstart + i] + ", ");}
   System.out.println("");}


  public static void longestBackward(int[] a){

int start = 1;
int maxstart = 1;
int size = 0;
int max = 0;

for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
 if (a[i] > a[i - 1]){ 
   start++; 
   if (start > maxstart){
     maxstart = start;
     size = i + (start - 1); 
     max= i - 1;}}
  else{
   start = 1;}}
System.out.println("");
System.out.println(max);
for (int i = max ; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");}}
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: The sense of this line needs to be reversed in your second function: `if (a[i] > a[i - 1]){ `

Comment: longestForward is working through the array from left to right and looking for the longest continuous sequence that is INCREASING in value. longestBackward it working through the array from right to left and looking for the longest continuous sequence that is INCREASING in value. Is that more clear?

Comment: I think the method works fine it's just the printing that's a problem. Because it prints out the right max (which is the length of the longest continuous sequence), but it doesn't print out the correct numbers.

Comment: Why don't you go left to right in both cases and just change the one line, as @HoboSapiens suggested? It would be much simpler.

Comment: ok I did that and it almost works except it gives me 4, 5, 56, 5 as output (which is almost right..)

Comment: so basically it's not checking the value at a[0]....I tried to change the first for statement in the backwards method to for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--), but when I do this I get an out of bounds error. Any suggestions for how to fix this??